# Single IMG centered in DIV multiple times in outer DIV aligned to the right

Tags: css, html

I am fairly new to CSS and although I have found examples for centring a IMG within a DIV, because I have a `float: right;` on an outer DIV it doesn't work as I want. This basically makes the DIVs appear in the correct place, but the IMGs are not central.

Here is a CSSDesk link for an example of my scenario: http://www.cssdesk.com/2pgBf

I'm trying to get the green share icon to appear centered both vertically and horizontally within the outer red boxes (DIVs).

I'm sure there are lots of enhancements that can be made to my CSS, but please only answer with solutions to my problem (though feel free to comment on this post with tips for CSS).

Hope that makes sense....

Comment: Have you tried `padding-top` for the green share icons?

Comment: Please add your HTML/CSS to your post.

Comment: @TylerH I had thought of that, but wasn't sure that was the best way or not.

Comment: There is no CSS property yet to center something vertically in a div, so you'll have to manage it with spacing/padding manually if you don't want to use `table` properties. I forget if `inline-block` allows for that or not.

Comment: It's not. Your best option is to work from the inside out. An image (set to `display:block`) of 16px by 16px. then add padding (if you need space), then use `display:inline-block` on the anchor.

Comment: @TylerH I tried `display: table-cell;` and `display: table;` but if I recall that didn't fix it either... if `padding-top` is the way to go, then I'll sue that.

Comment: Heres a way to do it. Not sure its the best but does work. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/8VeaG/)

Comment: @Ruddy Thanks, and also thanks for reminding me of jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `position: relative;` on the parent and then:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

On the child, this will center it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/8VeaG/)

Comment: Good option for this.

Answer (score 1):

This will work just as well and no positioning needed.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/8VeaG/2/)

```
.social-media-icon {
    background: Red;
    margin: 2px;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.social-media-icon a {
    display: block;
}

.social-media-icon a img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: This was a very good response, but I used Ruddy's so marked that as the answer... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

When i need to do that kind of code i set the parent tag, in this case the DIV to position: relative and the image to position: absolute, top:50%, left: 50% and margin: half the dimension just do this in your code:

```
.social-media-icon{
    position:relative;
}
.social-media-icon a img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
}
```